# Ggplot2 fixed limits for binned colous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I am making a contour plot with ggplot, using geom_contour_filled(). I want the colours to be discrete, and to have the bins and range of colours fixed for all the plots I make (in different R files).
I.e. I want to add limits or breaks to the color scale that I can control. But using limits= or breaks= doesn't seem to alter my results.

This is my example code:

```
library(ggplot2)

grid <- expand.grid(x=seq(from=0, to=5, length.out=11),
                    y=seq(from=0, to=5, length.out=11))
grid$z <- sin(grid$x/5*2*pi) * cos(grid$y/5*2*pi)

gg <- ggplot(grid, aes(x, y, z=z)) + 
  geom_contour_filled() + 
  geom_contour(colour="black") + 
  scale_color_continuous(limits=c(-0.5,0.5))
gg
```